# How to open multiple tabs with jquery $.each

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to open X amount of tabs based off the rows selected in a table. When the ajax call returns, it hits the jquery foreach but only opens one tab for the 3 rows i select rather than a tab for each selection(3 tabs)... Any idea why this would be happen? All the data in the array is correct and url generation is working. It's just not opening a tab for each item in the array.

UPDATE: This works in IE 10 but not chrome fully..it opens only one for chrome. :( Thoughts on how to handle browsers?

```
    //FUNCTION
function viewContracts(selectedRows) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Home/SetContracts",
        data: { contracts: selectedRows.join() },
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {
            if (data == null) {
                alert('There was an error viewing the selected contracts.');
            }
            else {
                openContracts(selectedRows);
            }
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert('There was an error viewing the selected contracts.');
            alert(thrownError);
        }
    });
}

//FUNCTION
function openContracts(selectedRows) {
    $(selectedRows).each(function (i, obj) {
        window.open('@Url.Action("ContractDetails", "Contract")' + '?contract=' + obj, '_blank');
    });
}
```

Comment: Is the data about tabs you're trying to open contained in `selectedRows` or the response object `data`? Also, opening a new tab is browser-specific behavior you probably will not be able to enforce.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with 'openContracts'. I was able to open multiple tabs (pop-up, depend on browser behavior). What's your 'selectedRows' looks like?

Comment: based on your `if(data == null) { !ERROR! }` statement, I'm assuming the `selectedRows()` function needs the `data` call back object (`data.selectedRows` perhaps?)

Comment: selectedRows is an array of strings. So for each string in the array, open the url with the string passed as a parameter...thus opening a tab representing the data linked to each parameter.

Comment: I updated the question and it does work in IE 10 but not chrome..any ideas why?

Comment: would try putting the `window.open` within  setTimeout in case browser limits opening too many instantly

Answer (score 0):

function openContracts(selectedRows) {
    $(selectedRows).each(function (i, obj) {
        window.open('@Url.Action("ContractDetails", "Contract")' + '?contract=' + obj, '_blank');
    });
}

works in IE but chrome limits it to one tab